# Recaptcha Django cms - captcha validation take more than a minute

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, ubuntu, recaptcha

After spending 3 days on a contact form, I thought I'd better ask. My server takes more than a minute to validate my recaptcha. The details are below.

I have a Django cms 3 and Django 1.6 app running on Apache2/Ubuntu 12.04. After loosing time to let cmsplugins_contacts to work in vain, I just chose to create my own form.

Everything worked smoothly and super fast on my local machine, but as soon as I go on the server I ran into problems.

**The form validation is not working, precisely the captcha validation takes more than one minute and my $.ajax call goes in timeout.**

It happens to work once in a while, but then it start again with the issue.

I've tried to change plugin to remove the captcha from the form and do it manually with the recaptcha-client. I really don't know what else to try.

This is a little sample of my code, I can provide more if necessary

Django view:

```
 ...
 captcha_response = captcha.submit(  
                request.POST.get('recaptcha_challenge_field'),  
                request.POST.get('recaptcha_response_field'),  
                settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,  
                request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],)  
 ...
```

ajax call from template:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '//{{request.get_host}}/{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}/contacts_plugin_submit',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                    //success
                },
                error: function(e){ //error
                                                }
            });
```

I've also found a guy that says to disable IPV6 on my server because a weird tunneling, I've tried to launch the command but netsh is not a program on my server. I'd like to try the commands below:

```
netsh int ipv6 isatap set state disabled
netsh int ipv6 6to4 set state disabled
netsh int teredo set state disabled
```

Should I try to go this way?

Thanks,
Lockit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it...

I hope I can help people with this, because I just think is crazyness...

**Disable IPV6 was the solution!**

Here how to do it with ubuntu 12.04:

add these lines to sysctl.conf file

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

then run 'sudo sysctl -p' or reboot.

Thanks to this answer to let me go in the right way: https://serverfault.com/questions/568006/connecting-to-api-verify-recaptcha-net-from-server-programatically-is-very-slow

Hope this will help somebody.